# TypeError: sequelize.transaction is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am getting the error: `TypeError: sequelize.transaction is not a function.` Using 4.x

```js
const sequelize = require('sequelize');

await sequelize.transaction(async (transaction) => {
  await ProjectFile.destroy({
    where: projectId,
  }
      }, { transaction });
    });
```

Answer (score 12):

The transaction object is inside your connector.

So, to call a transaction you need inform the connection first, like this:

```
const databaseConfig = {
    dialect: process.env.DB_TYPE,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,

};

this.connection = new Sequelize(databaseConfig);
```

Where `databseConfig` is the configurations previously setted.

And then, on your interation:

```
const t = await database.connection.transaction();
await ProjectFile.destroy({
    where:  projectId,
    }
  }, { transaction: t });
// If everything ok
t.commit();
// otherwise
t.rollback();
```

And, in this way you can use the same transaction on a set of calls in your database before do the `commit()`.

Comment: The sequelize documentation require this note, god dammmm, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you setup with `sequelize-cli`, try requiring your sequelize *instance* that is already connected to the database:

```js
const { sequelize } = require("../sequelize/models");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this also if you are having transaction in third parameter, it should be in options(second parameter)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67470911/6183464